# Using curl to login into https site not working, suspect godaddy verification having something to do with it

Tags: php, curl, ssl

I use the following general code to log into other https sites and pull records using forms, but it doesn't seem to work for www.voip.ms.  I've created a testing account so if anyone wants to take a crack at it and tell me what I did wrong.  (Warning, the site only gives your IP address 4 tries until it bans it)

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$username="meahmatt@aol.com"; 
$password="testaccount"; 
$url="https://www.voip.ms/m/login.php"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "col_email".$username."&col_password=".$password."&action=login&form1="; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

I've also tried setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE with no change

Comment: I sure hope that vital login info are not the actuals. If they are, I suggest you "delete" this question and post another after, because edits still show up. (*Just saying*)

Comment: don't worry fred, if you notice, I say that it's a test account, thanks though

Comment: Phew! That's good. You're welcome. Some do post actual vital information at times. It's always good to point that out, just in case. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem recently trying to use the `twitter` api using `curl_exec` from godaddy.

The magic was to disable both peer and host verification in the options :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // required as godaddy fails
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // required as godaddy fails
```

The error was a certificate verification problem.  I have no problem using this exact script on non-godaddy servers.

```
CURLE_SSL_CACERT (60)
Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates.
```

The full request looks like this :

```
  $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?..."
    $headers = array( 
        "Authorization: Bearer ".$bearer."",
    ); 

$ch = curl_init();  // setup a curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  // set url to send to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // set custom headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return data reather than echo
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // required as godaddy fails
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); // required as godaddy fails

// $info = curl_getinfo($ch); // debug info
// var_dump($info); // dump curl info

$result = curl_exec($ch); // run the curl

curl_close($ch);  // stop curling

// Check for errors and display the error message
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) { echo "curlerror::$errno::"; }
```

Also notice that `curl_getinfo` and `curl_errno` were invaluable at finding the problem.

tl;dr , friends don't let friends use godaddy.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this function if you like. It's helped me out a few times.
If you still have trouble try fiddler2 (fiddler2.com) to check for all of the headers and attempt to replicate them in PHP

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$fields['col_email'] = "meahmatt@aol.com"; 
$fields['col_password'] = "testaccount"; 
$fields['action'] = "login"; 
$fields['form1'] = ""; 
$url = "https://www.voip.ms/m/login.php"; 
$html = get_html($url,$url,$fields);

function get_html($url,$ref='',$fields=array(),$cookie='cookie.txt'){
//  $proxyAddress = '127.0.0.1:8888';
    $ch = curl_init();
    touch($cookie);
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; //browsers keep this blank.  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;U;Windows NT 5.0;en-US;rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    if($proxyAddress != ''){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxyAddress);
    }
    if(count($fields)>0){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    if(!$result){
        echo "cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
        echo "cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
        exit;
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
    return($result);
}
```